# Safari iOS 9 jQuery height and resize Issue

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, resize, height

I've been searching the internet for quite a while and I'm getting nothing. I've seen many posts about this however, I'm yet to find a solution.

The problem I'm having is on iOS `$(window).height()` is returning the height excluding the toolbars. When scrolling the toolbar collapses, assuming a resize would be fired I've tried recalculating the window height on resize:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    height = $(window).height();
});
```

However this isn't being fired. I've tried using `window.innerHeight` and that reports the same as `$(window).height()` so I tried `window.outerHeight` and that reports the height of the entire body.

In CSS I've tried `height: 100vh;` however this does the same as `window.outerHeight` and reports the entire height of the body.

In the meta data I've tried `height=device-height` this is the closest I've come, however this reports the height of the device excluding any toolbars.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Thanks,
Tom